# TypeScript nested correlated unions incorrect typing when using generic functions

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type a predefined configuration in TypeScript which is dynamically loaded into my application. The configuration is defined as follows:

```js
// Base object types
type Config<D> = {
  fn: ({ option }: { option: D }) => any;
  option: D;
};

type ConfigRecord<T extends Record<keyof T, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Config<T[K]> & { type: K };
};

// Helper function to type function argument
const typeConfigRecord = <T extends Record<keyof T, any>>(
  map: ConfigRecord<T>
) => map;

// Actual implementation of type
const tableConfig = typeConfigRecord({
  test: {
    type: "test",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: "test",
  },
  test2: {
    type: "test2",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: 2,
  },
});

const defaultConfig = typeConfigRecord({
  tester: {
    type: "tester",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: "test3",
  },
  test2: {
    type: "test2",
    fn: ({ option }) => {
      return option;
    },
    option: "A",
  },
});

const configRecordMap = {
    table: tableConfig,
    default: defaultConfig
}
```

I try to access this logic with nested generic function setup:

```
const dynamicLogic = <S extends keyof typeof configRecordMap>(variant: S) => {
    const selectedRecord = configRecordMap[variant];

    const dynamicExecute = <K extends keyof typeof selectedRecord>(type: K) => {
        const config = selectedRecord[type];

        return config.fn({ option: config.option }); // Error
    }
}
```

I also added the following typing to the configRecordMap:

```
type ConfigRecordMap<T extends Record<keyof T, any>> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ConfigRecord<T[K]>;
};
const typeConfigRecordMap = <T extends Record<keyof T, any>>(
  map: ConfigRecordMap<T>
) => map;

const configRecordMap = typeConfigRecordMap({
    table: tableConfig,
    default: defaultConfig
});
```

But this returns errors where the property `option` is an intersection of all possible option parameter types. How do I corrolate this to the `config.option` object?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAECEEMGcFNQPYCMBWsDGAXUmCeAHWaAKFgA98EAnbPQ0AYQQDsAzASwHMAeAEQD5QAXlABvYqFCtmALlAAKUYnyZ2LUAF85ShCrWzQvTQEphgyM1wBuCctUs5vGxpukK1WgXhM2XAEoY1AAm3AAqoOSYsMxB0KAB6MHcANawuAisoKEANKAWuPyCIuKSANoA0qDszKCp6ZmhALpyPhw8oRWNggBkYjhecpUuxMPEIKAAErAANoRUUgCuzFj6OAj99KxLK%20qQVJwLALbRmG6UNKCJzNCehK3%20gVRBwqBhEWRRMXEJSXUZWbl8oV5LZDpB8C0WG0fk8wvxiKYhIIwfhXOMAIJYBaQaZVQ74aawY7MTCQew1f50WDEK43UBBWCsSALaaYe6cGHPERU9mcxS2KI3bS2SRUuQAIkFmHF2RFUgMijsqw0iMEJUkGqosEwCyoFL0LBsGs0suNunJEqlMtsGlNOCImAATMLjWLQJKHY7rcbpHJFeblaqxHLJFqdXqlYa5ba5QGHKBHXaYyrXLTaJAkITeY8uRtYNnEk9%20aKHbAqC6NW6PTcy96Nb6FDoDTUVWZg8bQ9rdfryUaNTGzc3LQ6AMx1gf2m7O9uVgbuqVeu2SBv%205smNvq41h7uR5h9yQTyRxgzi9Hj2Up4jEKmMKEPQtBACy4LekWisXiOZSaX%20OTylkKF51QqKoaj%20BpmlvXwOS-Dpyi6ZwbDTPMC2CZ98BeV8Pnfb4v3AgF-wKfgQUkFFIWgzl0LhBE2xRVMWDpK5oRzdCXh5O8YIfdDiw1BkmRZTA5D45lWVQp4lxwDNCTkUlM3zDjORGYx6OubAglwZhIEOdh0AAGQQTgdMwgBld5Pg-fCqX%20Jj7zQ8FiIANz2dgLEE0BjKDTdLgY7A4EJLBYCCTkXhszi7PwUonKoFySUaVxjWQ9TNO09AAFEyAwBYokwyo3y%20Wof0yKzMj8jAoiCnNiLdcpPJDbzVPqtoXlKgKKofUoqTiq8O1AbcI1CgA6aRVwtRquAG48TCsUBxlSqgqGoaMRivYggA)

Comment: how about this, type VariantType = keyof typeof configTypes; const dynamicLogic = (variant: VariantType) => {....}

Comment: That does not work as TypeScript handles the VariantType and what is inside `{ option: config.option }` as separate unions. This will give the intersection over this union as that is the only guarantee that TypeScript can give. That is why I use generics but it does not seem to work correctly.

Comment: After several attempts, I always end up with the same conclusion: this needs to start with plain old JS data and validation, then up to guarding/asserting that the data is of a certain type: because going from "values" to "types" is possible, not the other way round...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very similar case was the reasoning behind [this since-shipped PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to tsc. I'd imagine that the reason you're running into this error is because there's an extra layer of indirection that the compiler doesn't (or perhaps can't - compilers are a field of many deceptively intractable problems) handle.

My advice would be to flatten your data structure, or just do away with the generics. If you know what your valid kinds will be, write (or generate) the type declarations statically. If you don't, you're handling them generally anyway, so just use their JS type.

Finally, if there's some invariant you'd like the type system to track for you, but it goes beyond conforming to an interface and requires a type guard or some kind of processing, you can use type branding and only cast the data to that type in your type guard/factory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).